How does one add a volume control to this circuit?
My uneducated guess is to add a potentiometer at R6. Can anyone confirm?

Image courtesy : amplifiercircuit.net

AlphaSixSierra - Hi, Your original question broke the site rule on referencing, as it included that schematic copied from elsewhere, without a suitable reference. After I commented to you that the reference was missing, another site member kindly found & added one. So I have removed the original request for you to add the missing reference, as that has now been done. Instead I'm leaving this comment to remind you for next time. Please familiarise yourself with the need to correctly reference any copied or adapted material which you post onto the site. TY


How does one add a volume control to this circuit?

A volume control is added by replacing resistor 'R4' with a 1 MΩ logarithmic potentiometer.
Here's the altered schematic.

Changing the potentiometer tap position varies the level of the input signal and hence the volume.
On the other hand varying the value of resistor 'R6' varies the negative feedback and thereby the amplifier's gain and input sensitivity.
The gain or amplification factor is the extent to which an amplifier boosts the strength of its input signal.
Input sensitivity of an amplifier is the signal level at its input, that is needed to drive it to its full capability.

No, this will increase source impedance to 500k (near the middle position) which cannot compete with the 22k input impedance due to R3. Input will be severely attenuated. That potentiometer will have to be low-kilohms.

Thank you very much for the correction, Simon.


My uneducated guess is to add a pot at R6.

Incorrect.
Adding a pot at R6 would be a gain control, not a volume control.  With R6 at 0 ohms, the circuit gain would be 1, not 0.  That is, there would be a signal voltage across the speaker equal to the input voltage.  Also, many audio power amp chips are not stable at low or unity gains.  With R6 dialed down to a low value, the circuit might break into oscillations.
Replacing R4 with a pot would be a true volume control.  Now, with pin 1 to GND and pin 3 to Vin, at full left rotation there would be 0 V into the amp, and 0 V across the speaker.

LM1875 datasheet mentions this important information:

If you add a pot in the feedback network to act as gain control, it will not be useful since minimum gain is 10. If it is set to a lower gain, the circuit will oscillate.
The solution is to use a pot on the input, for example a 47kOhm LOG potentiometer wired as variable attenuator.

Due to R3 stealing some of the input signal, I wouldn't recommend using a pot with a value higher than 47k. Otherwise the volume control response versus knob angle will be a bit weird. If VIN is connected to something that can drive a 10k load, you could even use a 10k pot.
Currently, gain is set to 21 (R6/R5+1). If you have way too much gain, and find you are using only a tiny fraction of the pot's range to get acceptable loudness, you can set R6 to 100k instead of 10k for a gain of 11.

Replace R4 with an 'A' audio taper (log) potentiometer, such as this kind:

If you use a linear ('B' taper) pot, the volume control will be too tetchy at low volume levels and too insensitive at higher levels. The value is not too critical since it's a voltage divider. You could  use 50kΩ or 10kΩ.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Your educated guess is correct, you could replace R6 with a variable resistance (a 3-terminal pot wired as a 2-terminal resistor).  But there are other, possibly better, options.
Replace R6
When replacing R6 with a variable resistance, be sure to select the min and max values of the variable resistance to suit your application.  Voltage gain will be about proportional to the value of this resistance.
The minimum value must not excessively load the op-amp output;  the maximum value must provide the gain required to hear the sound at the lowest (quietest) input signal.
In this case, the min value can safely go to zero, since this simply causes R5 to be connected to the output, and its value is 10k which will not over load the op-amp.  In addition, the minimum value must not cause the op-amp to become unstable.
The maximum value should be selected based on the minimum input signal, and how close to full power you want to achieve when input signal is at minimum.  I would suggest the value of 200k is probably close to what you need here.
Replace R4.
Refer to the answer by @AnalogKid
